# How to dynamically change the date for the date key in the items prop for react-native-calendars

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, react-native, react-native-calendars

I am trying to change the date in the items prop for react native calendars.
From the docs, it shows that it requires a date string as a key which then requires an array of objects to display for that particular date.

Something like this.

```
<Agenda
    items: {{
        '2019-10-12': [],
        '2019-10-13': [{}, {}],
        '2019-10-14': [{}],
        '2019-10-15': []
    }}
/>
```

However, I do not want to hardcode the dates. What I would like is to display the dates of the next week. This is the approach I have tried

I get the date using

```
 new currentDate = new Date();
```

I pass this date into weekly items to get my weekly items object.
The below function uses two other functions called `addDays` and `dateToString` to properly render the dates.

```
const weeklyItems = (date) => {
    const day1 = dateToString(addDays(date, 1));
    const day2 = dateToString(addDays(date, 2));
    const day3 = dateToString(addDays(date, 3));
    const day4 = dateToString(addDays(date, 4));
    const day5 = dateToString(addDays(date, 5));
    const day6 = dateToString(addDays(date, 6));
    const currentDate = dateToString(date);
    return {
        currentDate : [],
        day1: [],
        day2: [],
        day3: [],
        day4: [],
        day5: [],
        day6: []
    }
}
```

`addDays` and `dateToString` are my helper functions:

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
```

This function converts a date object into the form 'YYYY-MM-DD' which is what is required by `Agenda`

```
function dateToString (date) {
    const newString  = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return newString.toString()
}
```

I have checked to see if my dates were correct and they all check out. I also have used `currentDate` and `day6` as my objects for the `minDate` and `maxDate` props for `Agenda` and they work as expected.

After doing this my `Agenda` now looks like this:

```
 <Agenda
    minDate = {currentDate}
    maxDate = {day6}
    selected = {currentDate}
    items: {weeklyItems(currentDate)}
    renderEmptyDate={() => {return (<View/>);}}
/>
```

And this makes it stop working. I know that I have empty arrays in my weeklyItems but for now I am just trying to get the dates working and unfortunately they are not. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`m on mobile, so i can't run this code...

Try to return your dates object like that:

```
return {
    [currentDate] : [],
    [day1]: [],
    ...
}
```

Also you can rewrite your weeklyItems functions to iterate from 0 to 6 and dynamically set properties to object which will be returned.

Than in your component:

```
// somewhere in your js
// const dates = weeklyItems(currentDate)
// const minDate = dateToString(date)
// const maxDate = dateToString(addDays(date, 6))

<Agenda
  minDate = {minDate}
  maxDate = {maxDate}
  selected = {minDate}
  items: {dates}
  renderEmptyDate={() => {return (<View/>);}}
/>
```

Comment: thank you so much. the [] around the dates in the return worked. Can i just ask though, what does the [] do to the date that makes it work?

Comment: {day1: []} => object would have key 'day1'
{[day1]: []} => object would have key with value of 'day1'